# How to get the progress status of the copy function in PHP?

Tags: php, copy

I need to know how to get the status of the `copy()` function in PHP.

I am using this function to download a remote file, and I want a progress bar for this program.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'll need to write your own copy function. First check the file size through a HTTP HEAD request, for example with this solution:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php#92462

Then do this to fetch the file:

```
$remote = fopen('remote-file', 'r');
$local = fopen('local-file', 'w');

$read_bytes = 0;
while(!feof($remote)) {
  $buffer = fread($remote, 2048);
  fwrite($local, $buffer);

  $read_bytes += 2048;

  //Use $filesize as calculated earlier to get the progress percentage
  $progress = min(100, 100 * $read_bytes / $filesize);
  //you'll need some way to send $progress to the browser.
  //maybe save it to a file and then let an Ajax call check it?
}
fclose($remote);
fclose($local);
```

Comment: thanx for the help,then can we use this progress data with jquery to make a progress bar do we need to store it in file or printing it with echo can do the work

Comment: I think you must save the progress to a file. The best way may be to store the full file size to a file before the loop. Then you can just compare that file size with the size of the destination file (as read by filesize()) and calculate the progress in a file Jquery calls.

Comment: if i store it to file how to make it work for various users at a time

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a progress bar for a `copy()` call to my knowledge.