# track php copy() with a progress bar

Tags: php, copy, progress-bar

I may have skipped it elsewhere on SO, but if there is a way to track it graphically? When I have a `≈300MB` media file copied on a local server `(note, not remotely)`, the entire browser tab is busy, showing the rotating favicon only, till the copying is done. Then only does the page show any info intended for display `(file size, destination space available, etc.)` before the operation. Any hints will be much appreciated.

Comment: Well, the (very) old school method would be to flush the output buffers after outputting the display information, but before the copy command. The better way would be to initiate the request with ajax, and do both steps one after the other

Comment: Can you elaborate on the exact way to ajax the copy()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because PHP is server sided it responses when the script is done.
And not in between.
The browser tab is just waiting for a server response.

This means that its not possible with pure PHP.

So if You want to follow progress you need to make it async.
I suggest to look into AJAX.

Comment: Been thinking of it alrite. But how do you see an ajax call checking specifically the copy() locally? I can understand if I say get regular updates for, say, the width % of a css-based bar on the initial page. But here...

Comment: You can make a separate PHP file that checks the size of the file. If you call this file with AJAX you can easily see how much bytes have been copied.

Comment: Cool. Will see to it!

Comment: `"its not possible with pure PHP"` This is incorrect, it is possible by flushing output buffers. See this current question where the user is trying to refactor old (buffer flushing) code as an example. You are correct however that ajax is the better solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33301734/how-to-display-a-loading-screen-in-laravel-between-submit-form-and-display-data

Comment: Okee you are right. Didn't thought of buffer flushing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834799/how-to-get-the-progress-status-of-the-copy-function-in-php