# How to display a loading screen in Laravel between submit form and display data

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel-5

I'm trying to implement an application that is currently in a procedural format into Laravel 5.  The user inputs some parameters into a search form, submits the data and then the results are displayed in a series of graphs.  The loading screen that is displayed whilst the data acquired and organised is done with some HTML within the PHP processing page, as show here (original, procedural method):

```
// create an array to store data for each record per iteration
$recordArray = array();
// create an array to represent citation values to ignore, i.e. not interested in any publications
// with less than 4 citations
$ignore = array(0, 1, 2, 3);
// create a counter variable to use for progress bar
$counter2 = 1;
// create a variable to store time for loading screen
$timeDecimal = round(($len*$avg), 2);
// turn time into readable format
if ($timeDecimal > 59.99) {
    $minutes = round(($timeDecimal/60), 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
    while ($timeDecimal > 59.99) {
        $timeDecimal -= 60;
        $seconds = round($timeDecimal, 0);
    };
} else {
    $minutes = 0;
    $seconds = round($timeDecimal, 0);
};
// panel to display records loading progress, js updates current record in #progressPanel
echo "<div class='panel panel-primary' id='alertBox'>
          <div class='panel-heading'>
              <h1 class='panel-title'>
              PROGRESS<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span>
              </h1>
          </div>
          <div class='panel-body'>
              <p id='progressPanel'></p>
              <p>The <strong>maximum</strong> estimated time for this query is " .$minutes. " minutes & " .$seconds. " seconds</p>
              <h2>
                  <button type='submit' class='back btn btn-primary' onclick='goBack()'>
                      <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>
                      <strong>Cancel</strong>
                  </button>
              </h2>
          </div>
          </br>
          <div id='processing' hidden>
              <h4 class='text-primary'>Processing retrieved data...</h4>
              <div class='progress progress-striped active'>
                  <div class='progress-bar' style='width: 100%''></div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>";
// iterate through all records, perform search for each 100 records (max per call) and tabulate data
for ($i = 1; $i <= $len; $i+=100) {
    // set search parameters for current iteration (first record = 1, 101, 201, 301 etc.)
    $search_array = array(
        'queryParameters' => array(
            'databaseId' => 'WOS',
            'userQuery' => $queryJournal1 . $queryJournal2 . $queryJournal3 . $queryTitle1 . $queryTitle2 . $queryTitle3,
            'editions' => array('collection' => 'WOS', 'edition' => 'SCI'),
            'timeSpan' => array('begin' => "1970-01-01", 'end' => (date("Y-m-d"))),
            'queryLanguage' => 'en'
        ),
        'retrieveParameters' => array(
            'count' => '100',
            'sortField' => array(
                array('name' => $sortType, 'sort' => 'D')
            ),
            'firstRecord' => $i
        )
    );
    // gather search response for current iteration
    try {
        $search_response = $search_client->search($search_array);
    } catch (Exception $e) {  
        echo $e->getMessage(); 
    };
    // turn Soap Client object from current response into SimpleXMLElement
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($search_response->return->records);
    // save variable names for global use, author, citations and publication year
    $citations = "";
    $pubyear = "";
    $country = "";
    // iterate through current data set and tabulate onto webpage plus store in variable
    foreach($xml->REC as $record) {
        // create array for this REC data
        $authors = [];
        ob_flush(); // flush anything from the header output buffer
        flush(); // send contents so far to the browser
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                  setRecord(" .$counter2. ");
              </script>";

        // authors
        foreach($record->static_data->summary->names->name as $thisAuthor) {
            array_push($authors, $thisAuthor->full_name);
        }
        // country (if exists)
        if (isset($record->static_data->item->reprint_contact->address_spec->country)) {
            $country = (string)$record->static_data->item->reprint_contact->address_spec->country;
        } else {
            $country = "";
        };

        // publication year
        $pubyear = (string)$record->static_data->summary->pub_info->attributes()->pubyear;
        // number of citations, if zero then finish populating array then 'break' out of loop entirely (not interested in zero cited records)
        if (!in_array($record->dynamic_data->citation_related->tc_list->silo_tc->attributes(), $ignore)) {
            $citations = (string)$record->dynamic_data->citation_related->tc_list->silo_tc->attributes();
        } else {
            break 2;
        };
        // for this iteration map all the values recorded into a temporary array variable, aRecord (equivalent to one row of data in table)
        $arecord = array("authors"=>$authors,
                         "pubyear"=>$pubyear,
                         "country"=>$country,
                         "citations"=>$citations
                        );
        // pass the data from this iteration into the array variable '$recordArray', after all iterations, each element in $recordArray will be a single record or row of data for a single journal
        array_push($recordArray, $arecord) ;
    }
    // increment for next record
    $counter2+=100; 
};
// finished loading records, display 'processing' load bar
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>showLoadBar();</script>";
ob_flush(); // flush anything from the header output buffer
flush(); // send contents so far to the browser
```

Where the function `setRecord()` is from linked script, `script'js`:

```
// function that will overwrite current record in info panel
function setRecord(current) {
    document.getElementById('progressPanel').innerHTML = "<strong>Loading record " + current + "</strong>";
};
```

So, within the `#alertBox` There is some text that says Loading record 1, Loading record 101, Loading record 201, etc.

In Laravel however, I can't simply insert this HTML into the Model that processes the data as it can't have linked CSS and JS files.  Here is the Model, `SoapWrapper.php` that performs the same function as above and is called by the Controller:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;
use SoapClient;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Redirect;
class SoapWrapper {
    // SOAP exchange for WoS authentication
    public $auth_client;
    public $auth_response;
    // SOAP exchange for WoS search
    public $search_client;
    public $search_response;
    // number of records found
    public $len;
    // XML data to send as SOAP Request to WoS
    public $data;
    // array to store records
    public $records = [];

    // function to iterate and store all relevant data returned from SOAP exchange
    public function iterateWosSearch($submit) {
        // variable to store average time/record retrieval (based on calculations)
        $avg = 0.08;
        // create a variable to store time for loading screen
        $timeDecimal = (round((($submit->len)*$avg), 2));
        // create an array to represent citation values to ignore, i.e. not interested
        // in any publications with less than 4 citations
        $ignore = array(0, 1, 2, 3);
        // create a counter variable to use for progress bar
        $counter = 1;
        // turn time into readable format (mins & secs, rather than just secs)
        if ($timeDecimal > 59.99) {
            $minutes = round(($timeDecimal/60), 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
            while ($timeDecimal > 59.99) {
                $timeDecimal -= 60;
                $seconds = round($timeDecimal, 0);
            };
        } else {
            $minutes = 0;
            $seconds = round($timeDecimal, 0);
        };
        // panel to display records loading progress, js updates current record in #progressPanel
        echo "<div class='panel panel-primary' id='alertBox'>
                  <div class='panel-heading'>
                      <h1 class='panel-title'>
                      PROGRESS<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span>
                      </h1>
                  </div>
                  <div class='panel-body'>
                      <p id='progressPanel'></p>
                      <p>The <strong>maximum</strong> estimated time for this query is " .$minutes. " minutes & " .$seconds. " seconds</p>
                      <h2>
                          <button type='submit' class='back btn btn-primary' onclick='goBack()'>
                              <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>
                              <strong>Cancel</strong>
                          </button>
                      </h2>
                  </div>
                  </br>
                  <div id='processing' hidden>
                      <h4 class='text-primary'>Processing retrieved data...</h4>
                      <div class='progress progress-striped active'>
                          <div class='progress-bar' style='width: 100%''></div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>";
        ob_flush(); // flush anything from the header output buffer
        flush(); // send contents so far to the browser
        // iterate through all records, perform search for each 100 records (max per call)
        // and tabulate data
        for ($i = 1; $i <= ($submit->len); $i+=100) {
            // set search parameters for current iteration (first record = 1, 101, 201, 301 etc.)
            $submit->data['retrieveParameters']['firstRecord'] = $i;
            // gather search response for current iteration
            try {
                $submit->search_response = $submit->search_client->search($submit->data);
            } catch (Exception $e) {  
                echo $e->getMessage(); 
            };
            // turn Soap Client object from current response into XML element
            $xml = simplexml_load_string($submit->search_response->return->records);
            // save variable names for citations, country and publication year
            $citations = "";
            $pubyear = "";
            $country = "";
            // iterate through current data set and store to $records array
            foreach($xml->REC as $record) {
                // create authors array for this REC data
                $authors = [];
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                           setRecord(" .$counter. ");
                      </script>";
                ob_flush(); // flush anything from the header output buffer
                flush(); // send contents so far to the browser
                // authors
                foreach($record->static_data->summary->names->name as $thisAuthor) {
                    array_push($authors, $thisAuthor->full_name);
                }
                // country (if exists)
                if (isset($record->static_data->item->reprint_contact->address_spec->country)) {
                    $country = (string)$record->static_data->item->reprint_contact->address_spec->country;
                } else {
                    $country = "";
                };

                // set current publication year
                $pubyear = (string)$record->static_data->summary->pub_info->attributes()->pubyear;
                // number of citations, if 0-3 ($ignore array) then 'break' out of loop entirely
                if (!in_array($record->dynamic_data->citation_related->tc_list->silo_tc->attributes(), $ignore)) {
                    $citations = (string)$record->dynamic_data->citation_related->tc_list->silo_tc->attributes();
                } else {
                    // break from both loops
                    break 2;
                };
                // for this iteration map all the values recorded into a temporary array variable,
                // $aRecord (equivalent to one row of data in table)
                $arecord = [    
                                "authors"   => $authors,
                                "ID"        => "",
                                "pubyear"   => $pubyear,
                                "country"   => $country,
                                "citations" => $citations
                           ];
                // pass the data from this iteration into the array variable '$records',
                // after all iterations, each element in $records will be a single
                // record or row of data for a single journal
                array_push($submit->records, $arecord) ;
            }
        // increment for next record
        $counter+=100;
        }
    }
};
```

So although it will display that first bit of HTML, the `#alertBox`, it has no styling and can't call the `setRecord()` function as the Model can have CSS or JS links.  How should I be doing this?  With AJAX?  Or should I be passing the submitted data to another View to display the loading screen whilst it processes the data, then passing the data onto the final results page when finished?

**** Additional Info ****

I tried adding the links to the `echo`d HTML as well as some inline styling, but that doesn't seem to work:

```
// panel to display records loading progress, js updates current record in #progressPanel
    echo "<link href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.0/readable/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
          <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
          <style>
          #alertBox {position:fixed !important;left: 35% !important;top: 35% !important;}
          .glyphicon-info-sign {margin-left: 15px !important;}
          </style>
          <div class='panel panel-primary' id='alertBox'>
              <div class='panel-heading'>
                  <h1 class='panel-title'>
                  PROGRESS<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span>
                  </h1>
              </div>
              <div class='panel-body'>
                  <p id='progressPanel'></p>
                  <p>The <strong>maximum</strong> estimated time for this query is " .$minutes. " minutes & " .$seconds. " seconds</p>
                  <h2>
                      <button type='submit' class='back btn btn-primary' onclick='window.location.href = '/';'>
                          <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>
                          <strong>Cancel</strong>
                      </button>
                  </h2>
              </div>
              </br>
              <div id='processing' hidden>
                  <h4 class='text-primary'>Processing retrieved data...</h4>
                  <div class='progress progress-striped active'>
                      <div class='progress-bar' style='width: 100%''></div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>";
```

Comment: Read about `onbeforeunload` and `DOMContentLoaded` events. You will have to use them.

Comment: You should never put HTML in a model, that's what views are for.

Comment: @BrianGlaz yes, I know, that's what I'm trying to fix.  Would I set up a new View specifically for the loading page and pass the data from the submit form, to the loading page and then onto the final results page then?  At the moment it passes the data from a View with the submit form, gets and processes the data in the Controller and passes it to another View with the final data.